# Stop the same random int coming up twice in a row

Tags: swift, xcode, random, numbers

I'm trying to make it so when I click a button it generates a random int between 1 and 13 (inclusive), it doesn't give the same number twice in a row.
Fairly new to swift btw

Ive looked at many other topics on here and still can't get it to work.

random int function:

```
func randomIntBetween(low:Int, high:Int) -> Int {
  let range = high - (low - 1)
  return (Int(arc4random()) % range) + (low - 1)
}
```

and the button:

```
    @IBAction func higher(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Random Number between 1-13
    numberLabel.text = String(randomIntBetween(2, high: 14))
    print(numberLabel.text)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable that stores the last used Int and if that matches the new random recall the function.

```
var lastUsedRandom: Int = 0

func randomIntBetween(low:Int, high:Int) -> Int {
    let range = high - (low - 1)
    let newRandom = (Int(arc4random()) % range) + (low - 1)
    if newRandom == lastUsedRandom{
        randomIntBetween(low, high: high)
    }else{
        lastUsedRandom = newRandom
        return newRandom
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) i just edited it as i got a few errors when using it in Xcode

Comment: No problem, make your edits here as well and mark as the answer please.